# Does Mundo's cleaver really do 25% of the target health vs monsters?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does [Dr. Mundo](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Dr._Mundo)'s Infected Cleaver ability reduce monsters' health by 25%? If it did then I can see Mundo soloing Baron and dragon at level 14 or so. Paired with Soraka, he could do it at level 11.

Comment: MAXIMUM DAMAGE VERSUS MONSTERS: 300 / 400 / 500 / 600 / 700

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dr. Mundo's cleaver does a maximum amount of damage versus neutral monsters, increasing per level.

The values are:

- 300
- 400
- 500
- 600
- 700

Remember that this is based on *current* health, which means the second cleaver will always do less than first (if you're not hitting up against the damage limit).